# UIView in UITableView disappear when becomes firstResponder

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview, keyboard, first-responder

In storyboard I have a UITableViewController-->UITableView-->UITableViewSecion--> with static cells

in the same UITableView I also have a UIView that holds a background image and UITextView.

A click on a button shows the UIView and set it's frame, which appears OK, but as soon as I click on the UITextView or make it firstResponder programmatically the keyboard appears and the view disappears

the code when clicking the button

```
self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y+100, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height-100);
self.myView.hidden = NO;
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy paste us the code where you add the view to the tableview?  Are you doing it with constraints or with frames?

The issue you are having is probably due to the fact the UITableViewControllers automatically shrink the contentSize of the UITableView they hold when the keyboard shows. If you add a UIView to your tableView with addSubview: programmatically, you might need to add a flexible bottom resize mask to make sure when the contentSize shrinks in height, your view stays attached to the top and not the bottom.

Try this on viewDidLoad:

```
[theViewYouAddedToTableView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
```

Comment: The view is not added programmatically its all done through IB the only thing i set programmatically is its frame, I've edited my question to include the code. Also tried adding you suggested line it didn't work

Comment: Is the view that holds the TextView a subview of the UTableView, or is a sibling? Also, you are setting frames in a view that uses constraints. Mixing autolayout and frames is not recommended by Apple at all. You should either create the view programmatically and do addSubview using frames, or, use constraints and drag them to code to modify them when you tap on the button.